# Bootstrap3 column expand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, multiple-columns

In Bootstrap 3 I have two columns, however in some cases I have only one column (second is not printed to HTML via PHP).

So how can I set the firs col-md-6 to expand to col-md-12 if second column in not available?

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Content always here</p>
    </div>

    <!-- second column is optional -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Another content</p>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

dddd

Answer (score 0):

Do you display columns via php?
if so

```
if (!empty($first_col){
echo '<div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Content always here</p>
    </div>

    <!-- second column is optional -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Another content</p>
    </div>';
else {
echo '<div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Content always here</p>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: I know this solution but in my case this is little more complicated, so I am looking JS/CSS solution. BTW thanx for trying to resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use `col` or `col-md` class instead of `col-md-6`?  Just an experiment?